# Имитация нажатия на кнопку без события в конкретном блоке

Tags: javascript, html, события

Вообщем суть в чём. Есть сайт, скажем theta.tv, пишу бота который будет отправлять сообщения в чат.

Собственно алгоритм работы.
Сам текст сообщения отправляется сугубо по нажатию клавиши enter (keyСode=13) , в тот момент когда фокус наведён на input-е где хранится текст сообщения.

Как реализовать фокус на кнопке и нажатие клавиши Enter по средствам JS. События и.т.д не катят, формы как таковой нет, input служит просто как блок. Поэтому через тригер submit вызвать не получиться.

Кто что может предложить?:)

Comment: А нельзя просто вызвать функцию которая отправляет сообщение?

Comment: @AlexeyR. нет, код весь сжат, минифицирован, и скорее всего не в глобальной области видимости. Разбираться в 100 киллометрах кода опять-таки времени нет, ищу простое решение.

Answer (score 0):

Как реализовать

Фокус:
https://learn.javascript.ru/focus-blur

Покус:
https://learn.javascript.ru/dispatch-events